Querying Data From Salesforce to SAP BW/4HANA by SAP PI/PO as middleware?
I am new to SAP PI/PO. I want to know the steps to fetch the data from Salesforce to SAP BW/4HANA by SAP PI/PO as middleware. My case is that I have to pass a SOQL query to salesforce using rest API and the data that will come will need to be captured in SAP PI/PO, where I have to create a configuration such that the data I have to fetch from the API until I don't get all the records, because salesforce has a limitation of 2000 records to fetch at a time. Then we have to use the nextURL key from the response which gives us the URL for the next chunk of rows. until another field which is coming in response called done does not have its value as true. After The Data is gathered I have to send those data to the SAP BW/4HANA where these data will be stored in tables for which I have to do some ABAP developments.
=> In Short I need the detailed steps on how to perform this if anyone who had done this earlier and has knowledge of the integration stated above will be helpful.
Thanks
I have tried using the SOAP UI to test and it is working but don't know how to do the same using SAP PI / PO.
